# Wikitude instance in Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, wikitude

I'm trying to call the initialiser of the WTArchitectView in swift but I'm getting this error:

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

In fact if I try to find the initialiser in the Xcode auto complete code functionality it does not appear.

Is there any way to call that initialiser?

This will be the code in Objective C:

```
self.architectView = [[WTArchitectView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero motionManager:nil];
```

And this my translation to Swift 3:

```
self.architectView = WTArchitectView(frame: CGRect.zero, motionManager: nil)
```

Where self.architectView is WTArchitectView type and it is a View in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help someone one day

To call the initialisation you have to import core motion first.

```
import CoreMotion
```

Happy coding.